# How can I make a command to get number of squares?

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes

I want to make some squares like this picture (not beautiful really):

[image].

I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\crule[3][pink]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}

    \crule[blue]{1cm}{1cm}

    \crule[blue]{1cm}{1cm} \crule[blue]{1cm}{1cm} \crule[blue]{1cm}{1cm}

    \crule[blue]{1cm}{1cm}
    \crule[blue]{1cm}{1cm}
    \crule[blue]{1cm}{1cm}
    \crule[blue]{1cm}{1cm}
    \crule[blue]{1cm}{1cm}

    \crule[blue]{1cm}{1cm}
    \crule[blue]{1cm}{1cm}
    \crule[blue]{1cm}{1cm}
    \crule[blue]{1cm}{1cm}
    \crule[blue]{1cm}{1cm}
    \crule[blue]{1cm}{1cm}
    \crule[blue]{1cm}{1cm}

    \crule[red]{1cm}{1cm}
    \crule[red]{1cm}{1cm}
    \crule[red]{1cm}{1cm}
    \crule[red]{1cm}{1cm}
    \crule[red]{1cm}{1cm}

    \crule[red]{1cm}{1cm}
    \crule[red]{1cm}{1cm}
    \crule[red]{1cm}{1cm}

    \crule[red]{1cm}{1cm}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

Can I reduce my code?

How can I make a command to get a number of squares? E.g
`\numberofbluesquares{3}` I get 3 blue squares.

Comment: You are welcome! Do you like to have the squares separated or united (both horizontally and vertically)? If yes, the horizontal and vertical separations should be different or equal?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Yes. Thank you. Can you help me?

Comment: Percusse has already answered, if you don't like his separations, comment his answer, bye!

Comment: OK. I accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\foreach` from `pgffor` which is a part of TikZ.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, pgffor}
\newcommand\crule[3][pink]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\foreach\x in{1,3,5,7}{%
  \foreach\y in{1,...,\x}{%
    \crule[blue]{1cm}{1cm}
  }\par
}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

And similarly for the red part.